# creating marker with link using google map API - not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

hello i'm trying to display link to wikipedia value inside information window for each location that i retreive using google places api and google maps api.

i can show the obj.name and the icon of the catogry ,but for somereson the link for the wiki value just refresh the page and not redirect to the herf:

```
       var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow ({content:
    '<img src="' 
    + obj.icon
    + '" /><font style="color:#000;">'
    + obj.name
//    + '<br />Rating: '
 //   + obj.rating
  //  + '<br />Vicinity: ' 
//    + obj.vicinity 
     + '</font>'
    + '<br/>'
 //   +'<a href "http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/'
   // + wikiurl+'> wiki value </a>'
});
```

this is the fiddle for the page itself
http://jsfiddle.net/QUTfR/5/
please help me to understand what im doing worng

Comment: I cant find the marker into your fiddle demo link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part is wrong:

```
  +'<a href "http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/'
  //_______^  missing =
  + wikiurl+'> wiki value </a>'
  //________^ missing "
```

it has to be:

```
  +'<a href= "http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/'
  + wikiurl+'"> wiki value </a>'
```

http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/QUTfR/11/

Comment: how can i  only show:                                                     '<a href= "http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/'
  + wikiurl+'"> wiki value </a>'                                              if (type == "things_todo") in the function findPlaces()